# TypeScript Type Definitions for BigNumber

Tags: node.js, typescript

I'm trying to use [BigNumber](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js) version 4.0.2 in a TypeScript program. I've created a stripped down example of a simple Node.js program written in TypeScript that uses BigNumber for this issue
https://github.com/naddison36/node-imports

I'm really struggling to get TypeScript 2.3.4 to pull in the type definitions for BigNumber. Does anyone know how to do this? Here's what I've tried so far https://github.com/naddison36/node-imports#attempts-to-get-the-bignumber-type-definitions-to-work

Ideally I'd like to simply run `npm install bignumber.js --save`, `npm install @types/bignumber.js --save`, use ES6 imports like `import BigNumber from 'bignumber.js'` and have TypeScript just work.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import style

```
import BigNumber from 'bignumber.js';
```

Only works if the library specified a default export, but as you note in the github repository.

> Changing line 10 from export = BigNumber; to export default BigNumber;
>   fixes the above error but introduces the following error:
>
> Error:(6, 15) TS2709:Cannot use namespace 'BigNumber' as a type.

This is because the typings for bignumber.js are declared using `namespace`, instead of `module`. I'm not sure you can work around the typings as they are, but changing them so the beginning goes

```
export default BigNumber;
declare module 'bignumber.js' {
var BigNumber: BigNumberStatic;
```

instead of

```
declare var BigNumber: BigNumber.BigNumberStatic;

export as namespace BigNumber;
export = BigNumber;

declare namespace BigNumber {
```

works fine for me in all the normal imports of bignumber.js

```
import * as b from 'bignumber.js'
new b.BigNumber(123)

import b from 'bignumber.js'
new b(123)

import {BigNumber} from 'bignumber.js'
new BigNumber(123)
```

Comment: thanks, you have just removed over 200 TypeScript errors from my project. I'll submit a PR for the type definition.

Answer (score 0):

So doing this seems to work:

```
import * as BigNumber from 'bignumber.js';
const result: BigNumber.BigNumber = new BigNumber(2);
```

**Possible explanation:**

The typings declare a variable and a namespace both named `BigNumber`:

```
declare var BigNumber: BigNumber.BigNumberStatic;
export as namespace BigNumber;
```

In the importing code, what you imported as `* as BigNumber` refers to the namespace whereas the one in `new BigNumber` refers to the variable declared.

Comment: Yes, this will work. The problem, though, is you have to use `BigNumber.BigNumber` as the type. One way to shorten this is to do
```
import * as BigNumber from 'bignumber.js';
type BN = BigNumber.BigNumber;
const result: BN = new BigNumber(2);
```
But that introduces an extra type definition line which I'd like to avoid